# Vue router not rendering components

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-6

Im using Vue , Vue-router and laravel for this project , been experiencing this issue which got me stuck for days :( any idea ? i can't seem to find the solution for this problem. I don't get any error at all even the simplest foo bar template not working.

My App.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './components/App.vue';
// import { routes } from './routes.js'

Vue.use(VueRouter)


import Home from './components/Home.vue';
const Bar = { template: '<div>Bar</div>' }
const routes = [
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar },
    { path: '/', component: Home },
]



const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes

})


//Layouts
Vue.component('sidebar', require('./components/layouts/Side.vue').default)


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

My App.Vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
                <!-- Navbar -->
                <sidebar></sidebar>
                <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <router-view></router-view>
                </div>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

main.blade.php

```
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed layout-navbar-fixed layout-footer-fixed">
    <div id="app">
        <app>

        </app>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: Is your sidebar shown?

Comment: yep , its working. only router not working

Comment: Is anything from your Home component shown?

Comment: Can you try import Vue.component('app', require('./components/layouts/app.vue').default) in App.js

Comment: the simplest foo bar arent even showing so do the home component :|  , @story ks alright i’ll try it asap